# Are there negative repercussions from requesting an ssl cert from multiple trusted CA providers?

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, ca

I requested a certificate from a CA provider, but with a key size to large for a service I want to use. If I request another cert through this provider that is the appropriate size, they will revoke the old cert when they create the new cert. There will inevitably be a delay between the old cert becoming invalid and me uploading the new valid cert to my services. This will create a disruption with other servers using the new cert as well.

Can I simply request a cert from a different trusted CA provider at the correct length and have both certs live? Will there be any issues for my end users? Will a request for a new cert with a new provider trigger some kind of invalidation with the other provider?

Comment: By 'invalidate' do you mean revoke or something else? If the former, what makes you think the CA will do that? It's certainly not required, and it would conflict with good practice for handling cert expiration. In any case, whether using varying and/or multiple certs and/or certs from certain CA(s) matters to a user could vary depending on the user. If this a website and your users are people using browsers, probably not, unless they are paranoid enough to use certain extensions, or your server has set HPKP. Other users like apps or automated systems I can't even guess.

Comment: Changed `invalidate` to `revoke` in the question. Thanks for asking for that clarification.